# How to confirm credentials while the user is logged in? (on Firebase)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `Firebase` in an `iOS` app to provide server support to the users.
When someone wants to change his credentials (email/password) or his display name, I request to confirm the current credentials. Is there a way (an API) to check that the provided credentials are the ones matching the currently logged in user, other than perform a log out and trying to log in again, hoping the provided credentials are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below method to Re-authenticate a user using firebase

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var credential: FIRAuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

Email:

```
let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email,` password: password)
```

Facebook:

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
```

Twitter:

```
let credential = FIRTwitterAuthProvider.credentialWithToken(session.authToken, secret: session.authTokenSecret)
```

Google:

```
let authentication = user.authentication
let credential = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credentialWithIDToken(authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
```

heres the firebase link describing the user management in ios
[ios user management in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users)

Comment: OK. I was in fact reproducing reauthenticate, just by using FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn() when the login was too old, without knowing that it (reauthenticate) existed. Anyway, it does not seem to be what I was hoping for, this method will simply log the user out(I suppose) if the credential are wrongs. I was just thinking of a simple comparison under the hood, without going as far as logging out the user.

Comment: well in that case you can save the credentials locally then make the comparison just make sure to apply some encryption technique like AES 256 while saving your credentials.

Comment: I see. By the way how do you set the credential variable you mention in your answer? (I am using Swift 3).

Comment: you can create a NSObject class for user which will have all the data like name, email, password then encode the data and write the data into the file save it in documents directory. when user logs in load the data from that file

Comment: Yes, indeed I can do that. But I would like to know how you set the credential variable you mention in your answer. I didn't find a clear working example on the net for doing this.

Comment: that depends on the provider you are using,  for email  use .                        let credential = FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider.credentialWithEmail(email, password: password)                                                                                   for facebook use                                                                                            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)